# Facebook application with rails/passenger standalone/nginx... wrong url callback!

Tags: nginx, passenger, ruby-on-rails-3

Rails3 with passenger and nginx is awesome!!

I'm building a Facebook connect application, I use omniauth for authentication.

and I serve my application by using Passenger on Nginx. for some reasons, I want to use Passenger Standalone for running the application.

It works fine, and when I go  `/auth/facebook` It goes to facebook normaly and request permission. But when it goes to the callback url, the url is just the unexpected one!

```
http://xyz.com:12148/auth/facebook/callback
```

How to figure it out to redirect to a url without the port number.. to make the processing goes well!

**Nginx Configuration**

```
upstream xyz_upstream {
    server unix:/tmp/xyz.socket;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xyz.com;
    root /home/deploy/apps/rails3/xyz/public;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://xyz_upstream;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

The application at works well, but this is my only problem!

Answer (score 1):

You should probably have a look at this:
[Overriding omniauth callback url](http://www.kbedell.com/2011/03/08/overriding-omniauth-callback-url-for-twitter-or-facebook-oath-processing/)

Answer (score 1):

Using the following from the link posted above does work

(in config/initializers/omniauth.rb)

```
OmniAuth.config.full_host = "http://practicallygreen.com"
```

The way that I have this working is that I set a global variable called DOMAIN in each environment. It makes it work across all environments so that it doesn't break or need to be changed every time I change environments. My example is below

(in config/initializers/omniauth.rb)

```
OmniAuth.config.full_host = DOMAIN
```

(in config/environments/production.rb)

```
DOMAIN = "http://xyz.com"
```

(in config/environments/staging.rb)

```
DOMAIN = "http://staging.xyz.com"
```